# If/Else statement in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, frontend

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LgLwx6c/8/)

I have a navigation filter that when clicked, each project will be highlighted depending on what category they are under.  I would like that when clicking the #all-btn, all the items will be highlighted their respective color.  Right now, they are set to highlight black, but I would like to change that.  For example,

Graphic design will be green,
Web design will be red,
Flat design will be blue.

I would think that an if/then statement in the jQuery could achieve this but not sure how to frame it up.  I.E.

```
if (the item has class graphic) { 
    $("#projects").find("li.graphic").toggleClass("highlight-graphic");
} 
else if (item has class web) {
    $("#projects").find("li.web").toggleClass("highlight-web");
} 
else {
    $("#projects").find("li.flat").toggleClass("highlight-flat");
}
```

What would be a good way to set this up, and would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give your tab elements custom `data-*` attributes. In this case, `data-target` attributes.

```
<ul>
    <li class="default-btn" data-target="wrap" id="all-btn">All</li>
    <li class="default-btn" data-target="web" id="web-btn">WEB DESIGN</li>
    <li class="default-btn" data-target="graphic" id="graphic-btn">GRAPHIC DESIGN</li>
    <li class="default-btn" data-target="flat" id="flat-btn">FLAT DESIGN</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can simplify ***all*** of your jQuery to the following:

```
$('li.default-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#projects').find('.wrap.' + this.dataset.target).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Since you're only toggling a `selected` class, you can also simplify your CSS to the following:

[**Updated Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zh20tea9/)

```
.web.selected {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.graphic.selected {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
.flat.selected {
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to be best most efficient method to go for and works flawlessly with little code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `hasClass()`.  Something along the lines of:

```
var projElement = $("#projects li");

if ( projElement.hasClass('graphic') ) { 
    projElement.toggleClass("highlight-graphic");
} 
else if (projElement.hasClass('web') ) {
    projElement.toggleClass("highlight-web");
} 
else if (projElement.hasClass('flat') ) {
    projElement.toggleClass("highlight-flat");
} 
else {
    // do nothing;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated your [**fiddle to this**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LgLwx6c/10/) (remove console logging, left in there for illustration purposes only):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-filter li').on('click', function () {
        var clickedOn = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log( 'clicked on: ' + clickedOn ) ;

        $("#projects li").each(function (index, value) {
            if (clickedOn === 'all' ){
                $(value).toggleClass("highlight-" + clickedOn );

            }else if ($(value).hasClass( clickedOn )) {
                $(value).toggleClass("highlight-" + clickedOn );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[See docs](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
$('li#all-btn').click(function () {
    var toggle = $('#projects .wrap').not('.highlight-web, .highlight-graphic, .highlight-flat').length > 0;
    $("#projects").find("li.web").toggleClass("highlight-web", toggle);
    $("#projects").find("li.graphic").toggleClass("highlight-graphic", toggle);
    $("#projects").find("li.flat").toggleClass("highlight-flat", toggle);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/za4qLzb8/)

---

If you just want to toggle the class

```
$('#all-btn').click(function () {
    $("#projects").find("li.web").toggleClass("highlight-web");
    $("#projects").find("li.graphic").toggleClass("highlight-graphic");
    $("#projects").find("li.flat").toggleClass("highlight-flat");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/za4qLzb8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery hasClass():

```
if ($('#item').hasClass('graphic')) { 
  $("#projects").find("li.graphic").toggleClass("highlight-graphic");
}
```

OR

You could simply combine with toggleClass():

```
$("#projects").find("li.graphic").toggleClass("highlight-graphic", $('#item').hasClass('graphic'));
```

Here, `highlight-graphic` class will be applied if the item has class `graphic` else `highlight-graphic` class will be removed

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery is ok, but you can accomplish this much more easily just by using css

```js
$(".graphic, .web, .flat").toggleClass("highlight");
```

```css
.graphic, .web, .flat {
  color: white;
 }

.graphic.highlight {
  color: red;
}
.web.highlight {
  color: green;
}
.flat.highlight {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all if else and can use below code.

currentClass could be graphic/web/list

function changeTheClass(currentClass) {   $("#test").find("li."+currentClass).toggleClass("highlight-"+currentClass);
}